# What might happen to the animals in an aquarium in an apocalypse?

Tags: fauna, post-apocalypse

If humans just completely disappeared one day, what might happen to the animals in an aquarium?

Obviously, some might starve and others might feel the effects of the climate/climate change, but what other things might be overlooked when talking about an aquarium in a post-human world? Like, do some needed lights to stay on? In some aquariums I notice air gets filtered in, is that necessary to keep them alive? If someone was able to feed them, what else would they need to know to keep them alive?

Really any information on an aquarium in a post-apocalyptic (without zombies) world would help!

Comment: this isnt really about world building

Comment: Electricity goes off and the oxygen goes away.  Fish die.

Comment: This seems to be a garden variety “what if” question.  What would happen if the human(s) in a house moved out (or died suddenly) and nobody tended their aquarium?

Comment: Different fish need different things; tropical fish can be pretty fragile, crawdads can survive in a mud puddle. What creatures are you interested in?

Answer (score 2):

If they do not have access to UV light (from sunlight or artificial) then they do not get enough vitamin A and they die.

They need to be fed or they die. They need to have a method of oxygen getting into the water else they will die.

It doesn't look good for the posibility of anything living past maybe a week, because I have high doubts on the feasability of anyone being able to power the equipment you need, find the fish food and feed them all without dying to whatever apocalypse it is that you're facing